# How to save model configurations log as configs.yml in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, pytorch

How can i save Model Configuration Logs in the form of config.yml file in pytorch. As shown in picture.
[configs.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCzyy.png)

Comment: You can use [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have provided the image file that what i need as output. I want to save all configurations of pytorch model as config.yml file.